# How to search for alphanumeric substring of specific length in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string "ldhjshjds HdAjhdshj4 Hdsshj4 kdskjdshjdsjds"

I only want to search for substrings (alphanumeric only) starting with "H", but only if the string is between 10-20 characters.

"HdAjhdshj4" would be a match. "Hdsshj4" would not.

Would such a regex be costly on CPU cycles?

Answer (score 1):

`r"\bH[A-Za-z0-9]{9,19}\b"` looks for precisely that.

Comment: It should probably be `r"\bH[A-Za-z0-9]{9,19}\b"`; without the word anchors, it won't insist on the "word" starting with an `H`, and it won't really enforce the length limit (it will match the first 20 characters of a 30 character word, which does not seem the be desired). Also, side-note, you've got a typo in the character class; you typed `a-Z` instead of `a-z`.

Comment: Touché, from the examples given it does not seem like OP desires matches inside of words. Edited the answer to your expression.

Comment: Oh, and just to answer the OP's other question: With the word and character anchors and bounded quantifiers, this regex should be pretty darn cheap to run. Profile if you have performance issues, but I don't foresee any.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookarounds.

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)H[A-Za-z0-9]{9,19}(?!\S)', s)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nU3lK8/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `lookarounds`.

```
re.findall(r'(?:^|(?<=\s))H[A-Za-z0-9]{9,19}(?=\s|$)', s)
```